# Getting FileNotFoundException while loading the page using c# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display my banner images in my website using c# ASP.NET.When my page is loading it is throwing the following error.

Error:

```
/Upload/Banner/2015-07-09_01-50-41-PM_Medical-banner-with-icons.jpg

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: /Upload/Banner/2015-07-09_01-50-41-PM_Medical-banner-with-icons.jpg

Source Error: 


Line 88:         {
Line 89:             Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
Line 90:             System.Drawing.Image srcImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageDirectory);
Line 91:             using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
Line 92:             {
```

I am explaining my code below.

> index.aspx:

```
<section class="slider" id="slider">
                 <asp:Repeater ID="rptBannerId" runat="server">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="ls-slide" data-ls="<%# getLs(Container.ItemIndex) %>">
                   <img runat="server" id="imgCtrl" src='<%# resizeAndConvertToBase64("/Upload/Banner/" + Convert.ToString(Eval("Bnr_Image")),1920,680) %>' class="ls-bg" />

                        <div class="intro ls-l" data-ls="<%# getDataLs(Container.ItemIndex) %>" style="left:80%;top:35%;">
                            <span class="icon fa fa-heart"></span>
                            <h2><span>"<%# getSpanValue(Container.ItemIndex)%>"</span>"<%# getH2Value(Container.ItemIndex)%>"</h2>
                            <p><%# Eval("Bnr_Description")%></p>
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <a href="" class="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                                <a href="" class="button">Read More</a>
                                <a href="" class="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
              </div>
              </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:Repeater> 
                </section>
```

> index.aspx.cs:

```
protected string resizeAndConvertToBase64(string imageDirectory, int newWidth, int newHeight)
        {
            Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            System.Drawing.Image srcImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageDirectory);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                gr.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));

            }
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            newImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Gif);
            var base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            return "data:image/gif;base64," + base64Data;
        }
```

Actually all images are stored inside this `C:/ASP project/Odiya_Doctor_Client/Odiya_Doctor_Client/Upload/Banner/` path.Here my requirement is If i am directly inserting this path this error is not coming but i need if user will use any other drive and put this project(`i.e.Odiya_Doctor_Client`) the images should display so i make it to be dynamic.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: So what you need to do, is take the URL segment, sanitise it. Append it the end of the known file path. Check it exists, if so, serve it up.

Comment: You can try something like System.Drawing.Image srcImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(imageDirectory));
But you should call this with imageDirectory like : "~/Upload/Banner/" + Convert.ToString(Eval("Bnr_Image"))

Comment: @Callum : Actually my project name is  `Odiya_Doctor_Client` and my all images are inside `upload/banner` folder which is present inside my project.Here i need if i will keep this project any other drive rather than c drive it should work and i dont want to change direct path again again.

Comment: @Avi:Thanks your line started work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Server.MapPath

like:
(Server.MapPath("/Upload/Banner/") + Convert.ToString(Eval("Bnr_Image"))

change the folder sequence according to your application. Here is different options for Server.MapPath

Server.MapPath specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a physical directory.

Server.MapPath(".")1 returns the current physical directory of the file (e.g. aspx) being executed
Server.MapPath("..") returns the parent directory
Server.MapPath("~") returns the physical path to the root of the application
Server.MapPath("/") returns the physical path to the root of the domain name (is not necessarily the same as the root of the application)